# how to filter the posts of wordpress default post listing by using hook / filter on plugin or function.php page?

Tags: wordpress, post, filter, hook

I am trying to list posts belonging only to a certain category on the default wordpress blog page. I need to do this by adding a filter/action hook via a plugin. I can not edit the theme template files.

I have done this for recent posts listing using the following code:

```
add_filter('widget_posts_args', 'my_widget_posts_args');

function my_widget_posts_args($args) {
  return array( 'posts_per_page'      => 10,//set the number you want here
                'no_found_rows'       => true,
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                'cat'                 => 52 //$cat -> term_id//the current category id
               );
}
```

How do I do the same for the post listing page?

Comment: what have you done so far? please add the code

Comment: i am creating simple plugins for filter the posts on blog page. now i need to write code on plugins and filter the post by category on post listing.  I have removed from recent post listing  using code    add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'my_widget_posts_args');
function my_widget_posts_args($args) {
 
  return array(
   'posts_per_page' => 10,//set the number you want here 
   'no_found_rows' => true, 
   'post_status' => 'publish', 
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
   'cat' => 52 //$cat -> term_id//the current category id
    );
 
}

Comment: please check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-posts-filter/

Comment: @RockyPrajapati For future reference, when someone asks for code, edit it into the question itself instead of putting it in a comment. It's much more legible that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by default wp blog page you mean the frontpage. If not, use `is_home` in place of `is_front_page`.

In order to filter the posts by category before the query is run, you need to change the category parameter of the query `cat` in the [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook.

Add the following to your plugin code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_post_filter');

function my_post_filter($query) {
  if($query->is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('cat', '52');
  }
}
```

The above can be used in a theme's functions.php as well.

Comment: This might answer the question, but please also provide a short explanation what your code does and why it can solve the initial problem.

Comment: Added an explanation.